# Panoramic image stitching using opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, panoramas, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch two images by finding the keypoints and stitching the images accordingly using opencv and python (panoramic image stitching).  Luckily I found a code that do the trick.  But it works well with given images alongside of the code. And it is not working for my images(getting only the second image as the final resultant image). The code is given below

```
#import the necessary packages
 import numpy as np
 import imutils
 import cv2

class Stitcher:
def __init__(self):
    # determine if we are using OpenCV v3.X
    self.isv3 = imutils.is_cv3()

def stitch(self, images, ratio=0.75, reprojThresh=4.0,
    showMatches=False):
    # unpack the images, then detect keypoints and extract
    # local invariant descriptors from them
    (imageB, imageA) = images
    (kpsA, featuresA) = self.detectAndDescribe(imageA)
    (kpsB, featuresB) = self.detectAndDescribe(imageB)

    # match features between the two images
    M = self.matchKeypoints(kpsA, kpsB,
        featuresA, featuresB, ratio, reprojThresh)

    # if the match is None, then there aren't enough matched
    # keypoints to create a panorama
    if M is None:
        return None

    # otherwise, apply a perspective warp to stitch the images
    # together
    (matches, H, status) = M
    #print (matches)
    #print (H)
    result = cv2.warpPerspective(imageA, H,
        (imageA.shape[1] + imageB.shape[1], imageA.shape[0]))
    cv2.imshow("a",result)
    result[0:imageB.shape[0], 0:imageB.shape[1]] = imageB
    cv2.imshow("b",result)

    # check to see if the keypoint matches should be visualized
    if showMatches:
        vis = self.drawMatches(imageA, imageB, kpsA, kpsB, matches,
            status)

        # return a tuple of the stitched image and the
        # visualization
        return (result, vis)

    # return the stitched image
    return result

def detectAndDescribe(self, image):
    # convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # check to see if we are using OpenCV 3.X
    if self.isv3:
        # detect and extract features from the image
        descriptor = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
        (kps, features) = descriptor.detectAndCompute(image, None)

    # otherwise, we are using OpenCV 2.4.X
    else:
        # detect keypoints in the image
        detector = cv2.FeatureDetector_create("SIFT")
        kps = detector.detect(gray)

        # extract features from the image
        extractor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SIFT")
        (kps, features) = extractor.compute(gray, kps)

    # convert the keypoints from KeyPoint objects to NumPy
    # arrays
    kps = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in kps])

    # return a tuple of keypoints and features
    return (kps, features)

def matchKeypoints(self, kpsA, kpsB, featuresA, featuresB,
    ratio, reprojThresh):
    # compute the raw matches and initialize the list of actual
    # matches
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create("BruteForce")
    rawMatches = matcher.knnMatch(featuresA, featuresB, 2)
    matches = []

    # loop over the raw matches
    for m in rawMatches:
        # ensure the distance is within a certain ratio of each
        # other (i.e. Lowe's ratio test)
        if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
            matches.append((m[0].trainIdx, m[0].queryIdx))

    # computing a homography requires at least 4 matches
    if len(matches) > 4:
        # construct the two sets of points
        ptsA = np.float32([kpsA[i] for (_, i) in matches])
        ptsB = np.float32([kpsB[i] for (i, _) in matches])

        # compute the homography between the two sets of points
        (H, status) = cv2.findHomography(ptsA, ptsB, cv2.RANSAC,
            reprojThresh)

        # return the matches along with the homograpy matrix
        # and status of each matched point
        return (matches, H, status)

    # otherwise, no homograpy could be computed
    return None

def drawMatches(self, imageA, imageB, kpsA, kpsB, matches, status):
    # initialize the output visualization image
    (hA, wA) = imageA.shape[:2]
    (hB, wB) = imageB.shape[:2]
    vis = np.zeros((max(hA, hB), wA + wB, 3), dtype="uint8")
    vis[0:hA, 0:wA] = imageA
    vis[0:hB, wA:] = imageB

    # loop over the matches
    for ((trainIdx, queryIdx), s) in zip(matches, status):
        # only process the match if the keypoint was successfully
        # matched
        if s == 1:
            # draw the match
            ptA = (int(kpsA[queryIdx][0]), int(kpsA[queryIdx][1]))
            ptB = (int(kpsB[trainIdx][0]) + wA, int(kpsB[trainIdx][1]))
            cv2.line(vis, ptA, ptB, (0, 255, 0), 1)

    # return the visualization
    return vis
```

And I call this piece of script in my main code like :

```
from deeps.panorama import Stitcher
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f", "--first", required=True,
    help="path to the first image")
ap.add_argument("-s", "--second", required=True,
    help="path to the second image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the two images and resize them to have a width of 400 pixels
# (for faster processing)
imageA = cv2.imread(args["first"])
imageB = cv2.imread(args["second"])

imageA = imutils.resize(imageA, width=400)
imageB = imutils.resize(imageB, width=400)

# stitch the images together to create a panorama
stitcher = Stitcher()
(result1, vis1) = stitcher.stitch([imageA, imageB], showMatches=True)

# show the images
cv2.imshow("Image A", imageA)
cv2.imshow("Image B", imageB)
cv2.imshow("Keypoint Matches1", vis1)
cv2.imshow("Result1", result1)
img = Image.fromarray(result1)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My ultimate aim is to get a final text from combining the images(scrolling text). The images are attached. I dunno what is wrong with the script, or if you have other solutions please let me know

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may try `stitcher` module directly of OpenCV. It does all these things under the hood.

Comment: I tried the stitcher module.  I am getting error like this  
"OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (The data should normally be NULL!) in NumpyAllocator::allocate"

I am using python 3.6 and opencv 3.2.  there seems to be a bug in stitcher module.  For my application python 3.6 suits.. So is there any other way other than stitcher module ?

Comment: That seems to be an issue with your OpenCV version, there is a long thread on github related to this. I think it is fixed in latest releases, so you may build OpenCV with latest code.

Comment: I installed with the new version.  Still the same probelm occures while using stitcher module

Comment: My guess is that the stitcher can't find enough keypoints on your input images. Thus, it is not able to reliably match them. I think [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) would better fit your needs.

Comment: It seems like my images is overlapped with the black space maybe. and @elouarn - I want the final image showing "Cruise Control"..not only just two images, sometimes i will have more images to stitch , can template matching helps in this?

Comment: If you are able to find the word that has been cut ("_cont_" in your example) then you can use it as a template and locate it in the second image (thnaks to [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html). Once you have that info, it's trivial to stitch both images. Having more than two images to stitch doesn't make the problem harder imo.

Comment: Good Idea, I will try and update once i got the solution

Comment: @DeepanRaj This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45639406/5799975) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
stitcher = Stitcher()
```

try using `stitcher.create()` while calling an object.

Also, check the `opencv` version