# Panorama stitching for text

Tags: opencv, panoramas, image-stitching

I'm looking for a good panorama stitching library for text. I tried [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) and [OpenPano](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/OpenPano). They both work good on regular photos, but fail on text. For example I need to stitch the following 3 images:

[image: 1st]
[image: s2nd]
[image: 3rd]

The images have about 45% overlapping between each other.

If there's an option to make one of the mentioned libraries work good on text images, instead of finding another library, that would be great.

- I need the library to work on linux arm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OpenPano](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/OpenPano) fails at stitching text because it cannot retrieve **enough feature points** (or keypoints) to do the stitching process.

*Text stitching* doesn't need a matching method that is robust to rotations but only to **translations**. [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) conveniently offers such a function. It is called : [**Template Matching**](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html).

The solution I will develop is based on this OpenCV's feature.

---

## Pipeline

I will now explain the **main steps** of my solution (for further details, please have a look at the code provided bellow).

#### Matching process

In order to match two consecutive images (done in the `matchImages` function, see code bellow):

1. We create a *template* image by taking 45% (`H_templ_ratio`) of the first image as depicted bellow:

[image: Template, 45% of the original image]

This step is done in my code by the function `genTemplate`.

2. We add black margins to the second image (where we want to find the *template*). This step is necessary if the text is **not aligned** in the input images (this is the case on these sample images though). Here is what the image looks like after the margin process. As you can see, the margins are only needed bellow and above the image:

[image: margins are only needed above and bellow]

The *template* image could theoretically be found anywhere in this margined image. This process is done in the `addBlackMargins` function.

3. We apply a [canny filter](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) on both the *template* image and the image where we want to find it (done inside the `Mat2Edges` function). This will add **robustness** to the *matching process*. Here is an example:

[image: Example of the canny filter]

4. We match the *template*  with the image using [`matchTemplate`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be) and we retrieve the best match location with the [`minMaxLoc`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707) function.

#### Calculating final image size

This step consists in calculating the **size** of the **final matrix** where we will stitch all the images together. This is particularly needed if all the input images don't have the same height.

This step is done inside the `calcFinalImgSize` function. I won't get into to much details here because even though it looks a bit complex (for me at least), this is only simple maths (additions, subtractions, multiplications). Take a pen and paper if you want to understand the formulas.

#### Stitching process

Once we have the *match locations* for each input images, we only have to do simple maths to **copy** the **input images** in the right spot of the *final image*. Again, I recommend you to check the code for implementation details (see `stitchImages` function).

---

## Results

Here is the result with your input images:

[image: final result with sample provided]

As you can see, the result is not "*pixel perfect*" but it should be good enough for [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

And here is another result with input images of **different heights**:

[image: result with images of different heights]

---

## Code (Python)

My program is written in Python and uses **`cv2`** (OpenCV) and **`numpy`** modules. However it can be ported (easily) in other languages such as *C++*, *Java* and *C#*.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

def genTemplate(img): 
    global H_templ_ratio
    # we get the image's width and height
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    # we compute the template's bounds
    x1 = int(float(w)*(1-H_templ_ratio))
    y1 = 0
    x2 = w
    y2 = h
    return(img[y1:y2,x1:x2]) # and crop the input image

def mat2Edges(img): # applies a Canny filter to get the edges
    edged = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
    return(edged)

def addBlackMargins(img, top, bottom, left, right): # top, bottom, left, right: margins width in pixels
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    result = np.zeros((h+top+bottom, w+left+right, 3), np.uint8)
    result[top:top+h,left:left+w] = img
    return(result)

# return the y_offset of the first image to stitch and the final image size needed
def calcFinalImgSize(imgs, loc):
    global V_templ_ratio, H_templ_ratio
    y_offset = 0
    max_margin_top = 0; max_margin_bottom = 0 # maximum margins that will be needed above and bellow the first image in order to stitch all the images into one mat
    current_margin_top = 0; current_margin_bottom = 0

    h_init, w_init = imgs[0].shape[:2]
    w_final = w_init
    
    for i in range(0,len(loc)):
        h, w = imgs[i].shape[:2]
        h2, w2 = imgs[i+1].shape[:2]
        # we compute the max top/bottom margins that will be needed (relatively to the first input image) in order to stitch all the images
        current_margin_top += loc[i][1] # here, we assume that the template top-left corner Y-coordinate is 0 (relatively to its original image)
        current_margin_bottom += (h2 - loc[i][1]) - h
        if(current_margin_top > max_margin_top): max_margin_top = current_margin_top
        if(current_margin_bottom > max_margin_bottom): max_margin_bottom = current_margin_bottom
        # we compute the width needed for the final result
        x_templ = int(float(w)*H_templ_ratio) # x-coordinate of the template relatively to its original image
        w_final += (w2 - x_templ - loc[i][0]) # width needed to stitch all the images into one mat

    h_final = h_init + max_margin_top + max_margin_bottom
    return (max_margin_top, h_final, w_final)

# match each input image with its following image (1->2, 2->3) 
def matchImages(imgs, templates_loc):
    for i in range(0,len(imgs)-1):
        template = genTemplate(imgs[i])
        template = mat2Edges(template)
        h_templ, w_templ = template.shape[:2]
        # Apply template Matching
        margin_top = margin_bottom = h_templ; margin_left = margin_right = 0
        img = addBlackMargins(imgs[i+1],margin_top, margin_bottom, margin_left, margin_right) # we need to enlarge the input image prior to call matchTemplate (template needs to be strictly smaller than the input image)
        img = mat2Edges(img)
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF) # matching function
        _, _, _, templ_pos = cv2.minMaxLoc(res) # minMaxLoc gets the best match position
        # as we added margins to the input image we need to subtract the margins width to get the template position relatively to the initial input image (without the black margins)
        rectified_templ_pos = (templ_pos[0]-margin_left, templ_pos[1]-margin_top) 
        templates_loc.append(rectified_templ_pos)
        print("max_loc", rectified_templ_pos)

def stitchImages(imgs, templates_loc):
    y_offset, h_final, w_final = calcFinalImgSize(imgs, templates_loc) # we calculate the "surface" needed to stitch all the images into one mat (and y_offset, the Y offset of the first image to be stitched) 
    result = np.zeros((h_final, w_final, 3), np.uint8)

    #initial stitch
    h_init, w_init = imgs[0].shape[:2]
    result[y_offset:y_offset+h_init, 0:w_init] = imgs[0]
    origin = (y_offset, 0) # top-left corner of the last stitched image (y,x)
    # stitching loop
    for j in range(0,len(templates_loc)):
        h, w = imgs[j].shape[:2]
        h2, w2 = imgs[j+1].shape[:2]
        # we compute the coordinates where to stitch imgs[j+1]
        y1 = origin[0] - templates_loc[j][1]
        y2 = origin[0] - templates_loc[j][1] + h2
        x_templ = int(float(w)*(1-H_templ_ratio)) # x-coordinate of the template relatively to its original image's right side
        x1 = origin[1] + x_templ - templates_loc[j][0]
        x2 = origin[1] + x_templ - templates_loc[j][0] + w2
        result[y1:y2, x1:x2] = imgs[j+1] # we copy the input image into the result mat
        origin = (y1,x1) # we update the origin point with the last stitched image

    return(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # input images
    part1 = cv2.imread('part1.jpg')
    part2 = cv2.imread('part2.jpg')
    part3 = cv2.imread('part3.jpg')
    imgs = [part1, part2, part3]
    
    H_templ_ratio = 0.45 # H_templ_ratio: horizontal ratio of the input that we will keep to create a template
    templates_loc = [] # templates location

    matchImages(imgs, templates_loc)
    
    result = stitchImages(imgs, templates_loc)

    cv2.imshow("result", result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks very professional. I'll try it in a couple of days

Comment: Thanks, your code worked for me. What happens if the overlapping percentage changes though? Do I have to change `H_templ_ratio` accordingly, or is there a better way?

Comment: @AlaaM Yes, this is indeed the purpose of this variable. If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I believe this works for horizontal stitching, what changes do I have to make in this code for this to work for vertical stitching? I'm trying to stitch store receipts...

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV 3 has a Stitcher class which can perform stitching on Text as well as photos.

```
import cv2
imageFiles = [YOUR IMAGE FILE NAMES]
images = []
for filename in imagefiles:
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    images.append(img)
```

stitcher = cv2.createStitcher()

status, result = stitcher.stitch(images)

I got this result using your images.

[image]

Comment: Which specific version of OpenCV 3 have you used to stitch the above three images, could you please mention the exact version? I have tried it in OpenCV-python==3.4.18.65 but it doesn't work as expected.